# `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent` when opening app depending on installation order

Tags: kotlin, android-intent

I have two applications (App1 and App2)

App2 is able to be opened via intent if a custom permission is enabled ('com.mycompany2.app2permission')

I want to open App2 from App1 with a custom permission with an Intent passing some information

In my App Manifest of the App1 I have:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mycompany2.app2.app2permission"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

I have the following code to open App2 from App1

```kotlin
openApp2() {
    val intent = Intent("com.mycompany2.app2.ACTIVITY1")
    intent.putExtra("data", "somedata")
    intent.putExtra("data", "otherdata")
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        Log.d(TAG, "${result.resultCode}")
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Result OK")
            finish()
        } else {
            finish()
        }
    }.launch(intent)
}
```

If I install the App2 and then App1, I can open the application without any error

If I install the App1 and then App2 I have the following error:

```java
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=com.mycompany2.app2.ACTIVITY1 flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.mycompany2.app2/.features.app2.Activity1 (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{850f71c 7288:com.mycompanion.app1/u0a158} (pid=7288, uid=10158) requires com.mycompany2.app2.app2permission
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2425)
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2334)
    at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:2326)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1758)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1085)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1056)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:411)
    at com.mycompanion.app1.Activity1.openApp2(Activity1.kt:146)
    at com.mycompanion.app1.Activity1.onNewIntent(Activity1.kt:109)
    at com.mycompanion.app1.Activity1.onCreate(Activity1.kt:49)
```

Is there anyway to recalculate permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set exported true for target activity in App2 like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ACTIVITY1"
    android:exported="true"
    ...... />
```

If not please try this.

Comment: originally, that activity was without exported, but tried to build it adding the exported to true but in both cases we receive an error